# Working with multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, qtp

I have ten Excel files with names A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9 and A10 (all in .xlsx format). My requirement is to read each Excel individually, add some formulas and based on some criteria filter the data and copy the fifth column data excluding header (first row) to another Excel.

I did something like this, but it's only for one Excel sheet. I don't know how to change it for multiple Excel files.

'Start

```
DataTable.AddSheet "Sheet1"
DataTable.ImportSheet "A:\Trail 1\Data.xlsx","Sheet1","Sheet1"
RowCount= DataTable.GetSheet("Sheet1").GetRowCount

Set objexcel = CreateObject("excel.application") 
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open ("A:\Trail 1\Data.xlsx")
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objexcel.Visible=false

objexcel.Rows(1).Insert
objexcel.Columns(2).Insert
objexcel.Columns(2).Insert

objSheet.cells(1,1).value="Minutes Interval"
objSheet.cells(1,2).value="Hour Interval"
objSheet.cells(1,3).value="Hourly Filter"
objSheet.cells(1,4).value="HH:MM:SS"
objSheet.cells(1,5).value="Weight(g)"

For i = 2 To RowCount+2 Step 1

objSheet.cells(i,2).value="=A"&i&"/60"
objSheet.cells(i,3).value="=INT(B"&i&")=B"&i

Next

ObjSheet.cells(2,3).autofilter 3,"True"
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("A1")  
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy '--- to copy entire sheet data to    an intermediate excel

Set objWorkbookn= objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("A:\Trail 1\In   termediateExcel.xlsx")
Set objSheetn = objWorkbookn.Worksheets(1)
objWorkbookn.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste =xlValues '-- pasted here on intermediate excel
Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("A:\Trail 1\Result.xlsx") '--- open result excel file   

objSheetn.Activate  '-activate the intermediate sheet and get row count
rc=objWorkbookn.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.rows.count
Set src = objWorkbookn.Worksheets(1)
Set dest = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)
Const sourceColStart = 5
Const destColStart = 5
Const destRowStart = 2 'current row
Const destRowStart = 2 'current row
Dim currentRow 
currentRow = destRowStart


For i = 0 To rowcount
    dest.Cells(currentRow,destColStart).Value = src.Cells(currentRow, sourceColStart)
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next

objWorkbook.save
objWorkbook.close
objWorkbook2.save
objWorkbook2.close
objWorkbookn.save
objWorkbookn.close
```

'End

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like the following to loop through files myself. Also looping through a directory is another option. There's some posts already on SO on that you could search.

```
Dim filesToOpen

filesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel 97-2003 Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    Title:="Excel files to Open", _
    MultiSelect:=True)

For i = LBound(FilesToOpen) To UBound(FilesToOpen)

objWorkbookn = Workbooks.Open(filesToOpen(i))

'do stuff

Next i
```